# How to capture login button in JMeter

Tags: button, jmeter, capture

I am trying to hit "Login" button after entering valid Login credentials from CSV, however, I am confused with how to hit "Login" button.

Please help me with solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hit the button, you need to get the following information :-

View the source of file and locate your button., you will see something like

```
> <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Log in" name="op"
> id="edit-submit">
```

now, open jmeter and in your current sampler, add a variable. Give values like:-

Name : op

Value :Log in

Answer (score 0):

You can't really 'hit' a button with JMeter, unless you incorporate a selenium webdriver test or similar, then call it from JMeter.

If you know what action the button performs (ie submit a form), you can probably perform that action directly, but you need to know what request is formed, and send that to the server.

Try inspecting the page source to see if you can determine the action caused by the button, then emulate that.